# Re-aligning boxes to 2x3

Tags: html, css

I have these boxes on my website which is 4 across and 2 under it. But I want it to be 2x3 so its 3 on top and 3 on bottom so it looks more clean and professional but I cant get the code to actually do it.

Here is an example:

[image: example]

Here is the code that I have for it:

```html
<div class="tab-content">
                    <!--======= HOURLY =========-->
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="hrs" role="tabpanel">
                        <!--======= PRICING ROW =========-->
                        <ul class="row"></ul><!--======= PRICE TABLE 1 =========-->
                        <div align="center">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                    <div class="price-inner">
                                        <div class="price-head">
                                            <h4><b>Basic Package</b></h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>32 Hours Of Clasroom</p>
                                        <p>14 Hours of in-car instruction</p>
                                        <p>Meets State Requirement</p><a class="btn" href="http://championsdrivingschools.com/checkout/product/basic-package/">Choose Package</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--======= PRICE TABLE 2 =========-->
                        <ul>
                            <li class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                <div class="price-inner">
                                    <div class="price-head">
                                        <h4><b>Cruiser Package</b></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>32 Hours Of Clasroom</p>
                                    <p>14 Hours of in-car instruction</p>
                                    <p>DADAP Certificate</p><a class="btn" href="http://championsdrivingschools.com/checkout/product/cruiser-package/">Choose Package</a>
                                </div>
                            </li><!--======= PRICE TABLE 3 =========-->
                            <li class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                <div class="price-inner">
                                    <div class="price-head">
                                        <h4><b>V.I.P Package</b></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>32 Hours Of Clasroom</p>
                                    <p>14 Hours of in-car instruction</p>
                                    <p>Priority Scheduling</p><a class="btn" href="http://championsdrivingschools.com/checkout/product/vip-package/">Choose Package</a>
                                </div>
                            </li><!--======= PRICE TABLE 4 =========-->
                            <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">
                                <div class="mobileHide">

                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                <div class="price-inner papu">
                                    <div class="price-head">
                                        <h4><b>Road Lighting</b></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>32 Hours Of Clasroom</p>
                                    <p>14 Hours of in-car instruction</p>
                                    <p>Lighting Fast Finish</p><a class="btn" href="http://championsdrivingschools.com/checkout/product/road-lightning-package/">Choose Package</a>
                                </div>
                            </li><!--======= PRICE TABLE 4 =========--><br>
                            <li class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                <div class="price-inner">
                                    <div class="price-head">
                                        <h4><b>Blitz Package</b></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>Customizable Schedule</p>
                                    <p>32 Hours Of Clasroom</p>
                                    <p>14 Hours of in-car instruction</p><a class="btn" href="http://championsdrivingschools.com/checkout/product/blitz-package/">Choose Package</a>
                                </div>
                            </li><!--======= PRICE TABLE 4 =========-->
                            <li class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                <div class="price-inner">
                                    <div class="price-head">
                                        <h4><b>Drive Only Package</b></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>7 Hours behind the wheel</p>
                                    <p>7 hours of in-car observation</p>
                                    <p>Meets State Requirement</p><a class="btn" href="http://championsdrivingschools.com/checkout/product/drive-only-package/">Choose Package</a>
                                </div>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

If someone could please help me with this I don't really know what to do to make it 2x3

Comment: Just change `col-md-3` to `col-md-4`.

Comment: @Styx I just did that and it made it look kinda funky. How can I straighten and align it? https://i.imgur.com/2CJzn15.png

Comment: You missed some `col-md-3` to replace.

Comment: @Styx Looks good so far! https://i.imgur.com/SkEtYtI.png just one more thing. How can I add a space under to separate the top and bottom row

Comment: `col-`'s should be direct children of `.row`'s. This is not the case in your markup. [Read this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works) .. _In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows._

Comment: @zgood That doesn't mean that cols should be placed in rows only :)

Comment: @Styx Thanks for your help! It's coming out good so far. Do you know how I can add a space between the top row and bottom row https://i.imgur.com/SkEtYtI.png

Comment: @DaltonMetzler Just add `mb-2` class right after `col-md-4`

Comment: @Styx sure you can place columns anywhere you want. But the point I was making is that Bootstrap is designed to be used to have columns inside rows. Why fight that? In Bootstrap 3 columns need to be in rows to clear float and in Bootstrap 4 they need the row as the flexbox container. If you use the framework like it was designed you tend to have less problems

Comment: @zgood I agree, but have you seen OP's layout? First price has its own `<ul>`, other five have another. If he'll add `class="row"` to both `ul`'s the whole layout will break.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?